# How should I proceed when my answer was criticized unfairly and I overreacted?

Tags: discussion

I answered [a simple JS question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45110397/changing-image-logo-on-scroll/45110430#45110430) with a halfway solution (it only worked in one direction, but it was super easy to finish it) in a CodePen/CodeSnippet.

The asker pointed out that it did not work as he wished, and I became rude quite fast and told him that he should be capable of doing it by himself. (It's a professional website and I assume he gets paid for what he is doing.) I still think that I'm right but I feel like an ass for being so direct.

I know I overreacted; I apologized and told him what needed to do to get the code to run, but now I would like to know what would be the proper way to react? Being friendly all the way through even he can't change `<` to `>`, or not answer the question/discuss at all?

Right now I simply want to delete my answer with all the comments, since I think it's embarrassing for both of us. Any thoughts or ideas on how to handle a situation like this?

Comment: @francescalus It keeps getting better. But thanks good to know.

Comment: I did that the other day. An author criticized my 60 line of code solution because I failed to define an integer. I articulated how his "complaint" was annoying since it didn't impact code and appeared like he was being petty or wanting to be difficult. Before he could reply, I just decided to delete my answer entirely. Not worth the aggravation and on to more positive things. Unless it's bounty, I'd say just delete it unless you're hoping for other people to vote your solution up.

Comment: I've had similar circumstances. I know this is terrible (and this is not advice, so don't take it that way), but when an asker has an issue with my answer even though it's perfectly valid, and they blame my answer instead of their lack of competence in the task at hand, I tend to just delete the answer and stop responding to any inquiries from them. It's not worth the frustration, especially **when I feel they've lost the privilege of my help** by not respecting the work I've put into an answer already.

Comment: "*It's a professional website and I assume he gets paid for what he is doing.*" - not exactly, there are many hobbyists on the site as well. The official lingo is "*professional and enthusiast programmers*". Unfortunately you can be enthusiastic about a topic without having a clue :-/

Comment: @Bergi That's a big one. Tons of people are here - students, professionals and enthusiasts - and all of us have varying skill levels. Even some of us who call ourselves even "decently" seasoned with the frameworks we work with can get pretty dumb sometimes (has happened to me more times than I can count...). A lot of us just know nothing, or are too confident to want to understand anything. So people will react naturally on both sides. It's why questions like these are great, because they remind us to always be constructive and move on, with the spirit of the community :D

Comment: @Bergi Im programming since the beginning of this year and I would not dare to offer anybody to develop a professional/business website so I can't understand why somebody with even less knowledge than than I have would do it, but you are right I don't know if got paid or not maybe its his Dads website and he wanted to try some things.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts "when I feel they've lost the privilege of my help" nice one :D. Deleting the answer seems to be fair, I will do that the next time somebody gets mad/rude.

Comment: @hansTheFranz its not fair to all other people who have the same problem and can benefit from the answer, however. This is not a 1:1 help site, you provide answers for the benefit of the programming community. If you let yourself be influenced by one plonker to delete something, you're part of the problem too.

Comment: Funny that you'd ask such a question and mark Servys answer as correct given the nature of your comments

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> Being friendly all the way through even he can't change < to >, or not answer the question/discuss at all?

You should certainly be polite and professional at all times.  It's okay to be formal, or even terse, rather than being friendly, so long as you stay appropriate.

> Right now I simply want to delete my answer with all the comments since I think its embarrassing for both of us. Any thoughts or Ideas on how to handle a situation like this?

Seems like your problem is just the comments, rather than the answer, so fix that problem.  If you posted comments that you feel were rude, delete those comments.  If the OP has replies or other comments that no longer make sense, feel free to flag them for being obsolete; if the OP responded with rudeness of their own, flag those comments as well, for the appropriate reason.

If you feel that you can no longer reply constructively, due to having lost your temper, I'd suggest not responding at all.  If you think you've cooled down, and feel that you can respond (if it's even needed at this point) constructively, certainly take your time, but that's something you can decide to do.

But it sounds like the answer has potential to be useful, so I'd be rather hesitant to delete it.

Comment: Yes I should have waited a little before I replied, need to work on staying formal and professional. I already deleted a comment and will probably delete the rest as well. Thanks for the "has potential to be useful" I won't delete the answer but I can't change that anyway as francescalus pointed out.

Comment: @hansTheFranz For the record, I can't really speak to the technical merits.  It's more that you seem to think it's the answer to the question, and a good one, so as long as you think that, you shouldn't delete it.  You should only delete the answer if you think it doesn't answer isn't a useful answer to the question.  Delete your answer if/when you realize it's wrong, or is bad practices, or something, not because you posted (and have deleted) a comment that you think was rude.

Comment: Emphasis on the **not responding at all** if you lose your temper. Come back in a day or two and see if you can approach it more calmly.

Answer (score 28):

I think part of the initial problem was that you answered a pretty basic question with a code block with "That should do the trick" under it.

Generally you can expect someone who asks an easy question to not really understand the code in your answer, whether they *should* be able to or not. If there is any detail of it that doesn't exactly work for them, they won't really get why it's happening or how to fix it themselves. If they knew how, then they probably wouldn't have asked the easy question to begin with.

So, I'd suggest the following things:

1. If you're going to answer an easy question, explain your answer *really well* from the beginning.
2. Even after you've done #1, be prepared to answer some follow-up easy questions. Ideally, don't just answer in the comments, but instead improve the explanation in your answer.
3. If the idea of doing #1 and #2 sounds annoying, consider looking for a not-so-easy question to answer instead.

And regardless of any of that, yes, don't be rude in the comments, even if you think the OP is being dense. But that's not really specific to this situation, that's just how you're expected to behave here. It's good that you recognized that and apologized, but I agree with Servy - if you're tempted to respond rudely, it's best to just disengage.

Comment: the problem with #1 and #2 is that often when you do that, the op doesn't even say thank you and leave the answer un-commented/selected/upvoted what is even more frustrating but yes that is what I have to deal with when I choose to answer questions like this. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Keep in mind that your answer is not only for the OP, and in fact, if it's a really good answer it's _mostly_ not for them. If you think a question is worth answering, don't worry too much about recognition from the OP. Just be patient, and if it turns out that it is useful to the community, they'll reward you with fake internet points over time. :)

Comment: To add to point #1, don't forget that programming newbies often don't even know how to think about the problem, let alone how to try to solve it. Explaining in clear, unambiguous terms can be invaluable to the OP and help them understand how experienced programmers think. It's especially useful to explain _why_ you did things, such as (for example) why you used `var` at one point and `let` at another. Finally, it can be good to explain other options; for example, if you did `var a, b;` you should demonstrate how you could also put the variable definitions on separate lines.